# if condition always returns true within array iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, foreach

As part of a code along for a Udemy Web Development Bootcamp (by Colt Steele), I have the following javascript that simply lists items within an array, changing the console.log text depending on a boolean "hasWatched" condition. As it stands, the console.log returns all array items as if they were true.

```
// Create an array of objects. Each movie should have a title, rating and hasWatched properties. Iterate through the array and print out results and whether it has been hasWatched

var movieArr = [
    {
        title: "LOTR", 
        rating: 5, 
        hasWatched: true
    },
    {
        title: "Fast and the Furious", 
        hasWatched: false, 
        rating: 1
    },
    {
        title: "Let the Right One In", 
        rating: 5, 
        hasWatched: false
    }
]


for(i = 0; i < movieArr.length; i++){
    if(movieArr[i].hasWatched = true){
        console.log("You have seen " + movieArr[i].title + ": Rating: " + movieArr[i].rating);
    } else {
        console.log("You have not seen " + movieArr[i].title + ": Rating: " + movieArr[i].rating);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Many thanks!
Rick

Comment: Well looks like you did not copy it all `movieArr[i].hasWatched = true`

Comment: *if(movieArr[i].hasWatched == true){* theres a difference between *assigning* and *comparing*

Comment: ... or just `if( movieArr[i].hasWatched )`.

Answer (score 3):

You assign `true` to the property, but you need to check the value. You could omit the comparison and use the value directly.

```
if (movieArr[i].hasWatched = true) {
//                         ^
```

To prevent  side effects, with wrong assignments in conditions, you could use [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (YC), with a switched condition for checking, like

```
if (true = movieArr[i].hasWatched) { // throws: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Now the condition throws an exception an does not assign a value.

A complete working check in YC would look like this statement

```
if (true == movieArr[i].hasWatched) {
```

where the check for true is superfluous, because of the given and expected values of `hasWatched`.

The final checking condition uses the value and checks for truthyness:

```
if (movieArr[i].hasWatched) {
```

```js
var movieArr = [{ title: "LOTR", rating: 5, hasWatched: true }, { title: "Fast and the Furious", hasWatched: false, rating: 1 }, { title: "Let the Right One In", rating: 5, hasWatched: false }];

//first attempt
for (i = 0; i < movieArr.length; i++) {
  if (movieArr[i].hasWatched) {
    console.log("You have seen " + movieArr[i].title + ": Rating: " + movieArr[i].rating);
  } else {
    console.log("You have not seen " + movieArr[i].title + ": Rating: " + movieArr[i].rating);
  }
}

//second attempt 
movieArr.forEach(function(i) {
  var result = "You have ";
  if (i.hasWatched) {
    result += "watched ";
  } else {
    result += "not watched ";
  }
  result += "\"" + i.title + "\" - ";
  result += i.rating + " stars";
  console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, that was very helpful and learning about the YC checking was a cool new thing

Answer (score 1):

```
if (movieArr[i].hasWatched = true) {
```

Should be:

```
if (movieArr[i].hasWatched == true) {
```

Your assigning `hasWatched` to `true` every time.

Answer (score -1):

You're setting the `hasWatched` variable to true when you should be comparing it to true.

`if (movieArr[i].hasWatched = true) {`

vs

`if (movieArr[i].hasWatched == true) {`

Comment: Thanks :) - about an hour of frustration is over!!